# Can't return my result in async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

In an MVVM pattern I'm trying to make an `async` method that fetches a `json` string, and returns the result as a `List<Cabinet>` so that I can use this list later.

I have `json` that looks like this, it represents a list of cabinet object:

```
{"cabinets":[{"id":"1","longitudeGPS":"2,2891506","latitudeGPS":"48,8618687","cp":"75016","ville":"Paris","rue":"1 Avenue Gustave V de Su\u00e8de"},{"id":"2","longitudeGPS":"3,0566481","latitudeGPS":"50,6302592","cp":"59800","ville":"Lille","rue":"127 Rue Solf\u00e9rino"},{"id":"3","longitudeGPS":"3,8749271","latitudeGPS":"43,6110374","cp":"34000","ville":"Montpellier","rue":"17 Rue Foch"},{"id":"4","longitudeGPS":"-1,6736931","latitudeGPS":"48,1181043","cp":"35700","ville":"Rennes","rue":"127 23 Rue de Vincennes"},{"id":"5","longitudeGPS":"0,0991065","latitudeGPS":"49,4931952","cp":"76600","ville":"Le Havre","rue":"32 Avenue Foch"},{"id":"6","longitudeGPS":"4,8353320","latitudeGPS":"45,7639021","cp":"69002","ville":"Lyon","rue":"27 Rue Henri Germain"}]}
```

I've created the classes according to json2csharp generator:

```
public class Cabinet
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string longitudeGPS { get; set; }
    public string latitudeGPS { get; set; }
    public string cp { get; set; }
    public string ville { get; set; }
    public string rue { get; set; }
}

public class CabinetList
{
    public List<Cabinet> cabinets { get; set; }
}
```

Here I have an `HttpClient` that fetches the `jso`n from the website and stores it in a `listCabinet` variable.

```
public string adresseCabinets = "http://ppe3JoJuAd/gsbAppliFraisV2/webservices/w_cabinet.php";
public static string userId;

CabinetsList listeCabinets = new CabinetsList();
public async Task<List<CabinetsList>>loadCabinets()
{
    HttpClient clientCabinets = new HttpClient();
    var response = await clientCabinets.GetAsync(adresseCabinets);
    var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    listeCabinets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CabinetsList>(json);
}
```

When I want to return the `listeCabinets` variable I have the following error: `cannot implicitly convert type cabinetList to System.Collection.Generic.List CabinetList`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Unrelated, but why not `await` the `ReadAsStringAsync` too?

Comment: You aren't returning anything, you should show that code. You also use `.Result` which is bad practice, use `await` instead like before.

Comment: `listeCabinets` is of type `CabinetList`, and your return value should be of type `List<CabinetsList>`. You'll need to convert `CabinetsList` to `List<Cabinet>`.

Comment: May be you need to declare method as `public async Task<CabinetsList> loadCabinets()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of your method is `List<CabinetsList>`, while the output of `DeserializeObject<CabinetsList>` is a `CabinetsList`. You should deserialize the JSON as the type you want to return:

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CabinetsList>>(json);
```

Or create a new list to add the one and only cabinet to if the JSON contains just one:

```
return new List<CabinetsList> { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CabinetsList>(json) };
```

Side note: and of course `await` the result:

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Whilst this is most likely correct, I believe it would be worth noting that the OP uses `.Result` on the `ReadAsStringAsync` method when they should be using `await`.

Comment: Does he really do that? Edited @TheLethalCoder

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and let you know. Sorry if there is any mistakes in the code I'm still learning how to use asynchronous coding.